# pyinstaller add folder with images in exe file

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyinstaller

I have a python script called main.py that uses some images in the same path, in images folder.

I want to create one exe file that has also the images that are used from main.py script.

```
myprogram 
|-images_folder 
|-main.py
```

How I have to do?

I am launching:

```
pyinstaller --onefile --windowed main.py
```

But it generates a main.exe that can't visualize the images, because they are not included in exe.

Comment: I found this question with answer about the subject: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674790/bundling-data-files-with-pyinstaller-onefile

Answer (score 28):

To include the images in your .exe file, you need to specify them in a .spec file:

```
# -*- mode: python -*-

block_cipher = None


a = Analysis(['main.py'],
             pathex=['C:\\Python36\\Scripts'],
             binaries=[],
             datas=[],
             hiddenimports=[],
             hookspath=[],
             runtime_hooks=[],
             excludes=[],
             win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
             win_private_assemblies=False,
             cipher=block_cipher)

a.datas += [('image.png','path_to_image', "DATA")]

pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
             cipher=block_cipher)

exe = EXE(pyz,
          a.scripts,
          a.binaries,
          a.zipfiles,
          a.datas,
          name='Name of your program',
          debug=False,
          strip=False,
          upx=True,
          console=False)
```

Save it as main.spec and run it with `pyinstaller main.spec`
Don't forget to replace "image.png" with your actual image file and "path_to_image" with the file path to your image. Also, set `pathex=` whatever directory your "main.py" file is in.

This will ensure the images are stored within the executable file. To access them, add this fucntion to your main.py file:

```
import os

def resource_path(relative_path):
    try:
        base_path = sys._MEIPASS
    except Exception:
        base_path = os.path.abspath(".")

    return os.path.join(base_path, relative_path)
```

Then, every time you would use the file name "image.png", replace it with `resource_path("image.png")`.

Answer (score 11):

Just to improve the last answer by Francisco Rodrigues.

```
    a.datas += [('image.png','path_to_image', "DATA")]
```

The 'path_to_image' more likely means the image path with "image.png" behind.

Like this:

```
    a.datas += [('image.png','C:\\User\\user\\Desktop\\image.png', "DATA")]
```

Instead of :

```
    a.datas += [('image.png','C:\\User\\user\\Desktop', "DATA")]
```

or there's an error saying "cannot find " the file.

Answer (score 0):

Just adding one more thing I encountered while following the advice from Book Sun and ArmindoFlores - when all your image files are stored in a folder, you have to add that to your relative path.

For example in the python script:

```
resource_path("image_folder\image.png")
```

and in the .spec file:

```
a.datas += [('image_folder\image.png','C:\\User\\user\\Desktop\\image.png', 'DATA')]
```

This might be obvious to some people but I ran into that error when I tried to implement this solution!