# Python, Pyinstaller, Images, Sounds

Tags: python, image, audio, pyinstaller, executable

I'm running Python 3.7 & Pyinstaller 3.6.
I created a script which uses Pygame.
The script will display a number of images when the user
clicks on a certain button.

All of the images are in a folder, called "Images".
There are over 20 separate image files in this folder.
For simplicity's sake, let's call these images
"a1.png", "a2.png", "a3.png", "a4.png", & "a5.png".

The script also uses audio files, one of which is a ".wav" file,
& the other is a ".mp3" file.

These audio files are in a folder called "AudioStuff".

I've been trying to create an executable for my script
for the past 2 weeks, but nothing seems to work.

I can now create an executable w/o any audio or video just fine.
I can also create an executable w/ the audio files.
I did this by using this code to my script:

```
def resource_path(relative_path):
     if hasattr(sys, '_MEIPASS'):
         return os.path.join(sys._MEIPASS, relative_path)
     return os.path.join(os.path.abspath("."), relative_path)
```

I also modified how I call Pyinstaller:
pyinstaller --onefile -w --add-data "myaudiofile1.wav;." --add-data "myaudiofile2.mp3;." script.py

This creates an executable which works.
However, how do I modify either my script, or how I call Pyinstaller,
so that I can also include multiple image files in a folder?

Thanks.

Update:

I found this link:
[pyinstaller add folder with images in exe file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51264169/pyinstaller-add-folder-with-images-in-exe-file)

It helps w/ the image component, but how do I do audio too?

Comment: Oh, I should mention: I can run the file in Pycharm. I made 2 versions. The one in Pycharm has the audio files in a diff. folder. The one where I was able to successfully create the executable, I put the audio files in the same folder as my script file.