# Convert .py file to .exe file (I used text files and images to build the py file)

Tags: python, windows, cmd, pyinstaller, exe

I just finished my app and I would like to convert my script/file into an executable file. I've used some text files, images and stuff to build it.

Once I convert my py file into exe file, it will only work if it is on the same folder where the images, text files and the actual py file are.

I created a zip file and it works, but as I said, when you wanna run it you will see all the images, information... It does not look good for anyone who downloaded it

> I also wanted to say thank you for the people who helped me with my other questions about fixing my program. I dont know how to tag them, but thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [pyinstaller add folder with images in exe file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51264169/pyinstaller-add-folder-with-images-in-exe-file)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would reccommend using auto-py-to-exe, a wrapper program that simplifies a lot of the tasks of using pyinstaller, a program that bundles python and the scripts into an executable.

```sh
pip install auto-py-to-exe
```

it can then be run with

```sh
auto-py-to-exe
```

It should open a new window where you can configure options (such as if you want to have a single executable file or if averything is in a folder. If your assets (images, etc.) are in a different folder, then you may have to add them to the bundle by configuring the options in the auto-py-to-exe window.